# Python SimpleHTTPServer in LAN between 2 PCs

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple HTTPServer in LAN. PC-A(192.168.2.10) and PC-B(192.168.2.12) are in same LAN.

I want to access HTTPServer running in PC-A from PC-B using a firefox web browser.

In PC-A(192.168.2.10) I ran, 
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer $ Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000

From PC-A I(192.168.2.10) can access HTTPServer using firefoxx web browser

```
with,
1. http://192.168.2.10:8000  <-- WORKS
2. http://127.0.0.1:8000     <-- WORKS
```

But from PC-B (192.168.2.12) if I try to connect with

```
1. http://192.168.2.10:8000  <-- Does NOT WORK ??
```

Is it possible to connect to PC-A's HTTPserver from PC-B from above steps? OR are some other settings will be needed ?

Comment: Looks like a network or firewall issue. The server runs as it should.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you should enable HTTP port in your router via virtual server or port forwarding depending on the kind of the router.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an network issue in my LAN. Issue solved after I Switched to another PC-C and ran

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 
$ Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000
```

I was able to connect to PC-C's HTTPserver from PC-B. Issue was solved although not sure what was the real cause.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can you confirm that the PC that doesnt work has Python 2.7.15+ while the other that works has a older version? (Python 2.7.12 for example) 
It's my case and and I noticed they changed stuff in `SimpleHTTPServer` between those version...